# Error envio formulario con PHP

Tags: php, html

He creado un formulario con HTML y, posteriormente, he realizado la programación básica con PHP para enviar un mensaje desde una página web a un correo. El código usado es el siguiente.

Pagina.HTML

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contacta:</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="apellidouno">Apellido:</label>
                <input type="text" name="apellidouno" id="apellidouno" 
                value="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="correo">Correo:</label>
                <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" value="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
                <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" value="" />
            </li>
        </ul>

        <p class="legend">Comentario:*</p>
        <label for="comments"></label><textarea id="comments" 
        class="espectativas" name="comentario" cols="50" rows="7"> 
        </textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="aceptar" />
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar" id="borrar" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Código enviar.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['nombre']) &&
isset($_POST['apellidouno']) && !empty($_POST['apellidouno']) &&
isset($_POST['correo']) && !empty($_POST['correo']) &&
isset($_POST['telefono']) && !empty($_POST['telefono']) &&
isset($_POST['comentario']) && !empty($_POST['comentario']))
{
    $destino="ejemplo@mail.xxx";
    $desde="From:"."página web";
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidouno=$_POST['apellidouno'];
    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
    $telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
    $comentario=$_POST['comentario'];
   mail($destino,$nombre,$apellidouno,$correo,$telefono,$comentario,$desde);
    echo "Correu enviat...";
}else{
    echo "Problemas al enviar. Revisi que hagi plenat tots els camps.";
}

?>
```

El problema es que los mensajes no llegan a su destino y no se a que se debe.

Saludos,

Comment: ¿qué mensaje se imprime?

Comment: Revisa [la documentación de la función `mail`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php), la misma acepta por lo general **4 parámetros** bien especificados, mientras que tú le estás enviando parámetros posiblemente incomptabiles. Debes formatear adecuadamente tus parámetros y enviarlos como está indicado en la documentación.

Comment: @ErnestoRM la cosa es que sale "mensaje enviado" pero realmente no llega al gmail. Tampoco sale ningun error ni nada por el estilo.

Comment: @A. Cedano de acuerdo, revisaré la documentación de la función mail. A que te refierrw con formatear los parametros adecuadamente?

Comment: ¿estás en localhost?

Comment: Otra cosa, debes configurar el servidor para que pueda enviar correos en el php.ini. Allí colocas los parámetros como el puerto la dirección y demás.

Comment: Si, las pruebas las realizo en un servidor comprado @ErnestoRM

Comment: @zerocool de acuerdo contactare con la empresa del servidor y preguntare como se configura esto del servidor

Comment: Me refiero a que cada parámetro debe ir donde corresponde... a poner les header del email, etc. Tal y como explica el Manual. `mail`  es una función como cualquier otra y si a una función le pasas parámetros de más o de menos, fallará, a no ser que estos sean opcionales. En tu actual código tu pasas una serie de parámetros que no corresponden a nada y por eso el código no funciona. En el enlace de mi anterior comentario puedes ver algunos ejemplos de cómo funciona `mail`.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por ayudar, luego cuando llegue a casa lo pruebo todo @zerocool ErnestoRM y A. Cedano